# Select parameter less constructor with MEF conventions

Tags: c#, mef

I am trying to use MEF conventions within the .NET Framework 4.5 and am stuck on something I thought should be simple.

I want to export a set of classes and all are working except for the one that has more than one constructor so MEF by default calls the constructor with the most parameters which is causing a break as the parameters are aren't importing which is how it should be I guess.

Anyway, I want to make sure it works by telling MEF to export the constructor with no parameters.

```
var registration = new RegistrationBuilder();

registration.ForTypesDerivedFrom<TestStepResult>()
    .Export<TestStepResult>()
    .SelectConstructor(xxx);
```

So I know I need to do something in the SelectConstructor but cannot find what should be there to say to call the constructor with no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is:

```
registration.ForTypesDerivedFrom<TestStepResult>()
   .Export<TestStepResult>()
   .SelectConstructor(ctorInfos => 
                      {
                          var parameterLessCtor = ctorInfos.FirstOrDefault(ci => ci.GetParameters().Length == 0);
                          if (parameterLessCtor != null)
                              return parameterLessCtor;
                          else
                              return ctorInfos.First();
                      });
```

Note that it include some simple error handling. If there is no parameterless .ctor it returns the first one available. This might not be what you need though. You will have to decide on how to handle this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason it raises an `InvalidOperationException` saying that the Sequence contains no matching element.

Comment: @Firedragon This is because there is no parameterless .ctor for a part derived from TestStepResult. You need to either make sure that all such parts have a parameterless .ctor or you need to add error handling. I will update my answer to include some simple error handling.

Comment: Thanks for the response and that makes sense. I am sure I am going to understand this all eventually and it is starting to make more sense so appreciate the help! I guess then it might become more complicated to get the error checking to be able to call the right constructor when there is no guarentee of the constructor provided by a specific implementation

Comment: @Firedragon I agree it can get quite complicated. If you can keep it simple it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: This is good and works however, if a class doesn't have any user defined constructor then it fails. I thought C# automatically provides a default constructor but this doesn't seem to work when using the `First()` as above. It appears `FirstOrDefault()` is the way to go here. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply decorate the preferred constructor with the `[ImportingConstructor]` attribute?

Comment: This is one way of doing it, however that means needing access to the code that holds the constructor which I may not have access to.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only step you're missing is:

```
registration.ForTypesDerivedFrom<TestStepResult>()
  .Export<TestStepResult>()
  .SelectConstructor(ctorInfos => ctorInfos[0]);
```

Where ctorInfos is contains the array of ctors you have for the export in question.

Comment: Unfortunately that causes an out of range exception for some reason